# Constructing an array to specific format from two different arrays

Tags: php

Easiest to go straight to code:

Format needed:

```
0 => 
  array (size=3)
    0 => string '6100' (length=4)
    1 => string '6102' (length=4)
    2 => string '2' (length=1)
1 => 
  array (size=3)
    0 => string '6101' (length=4)
    1 => string '1' (length=1)
    2 => string '6' (length=1)
2 => 
  array (size=2)
    0 => string '7' (length=1)
    1 => string '5' (length=1)
```

I can construct the array easy enough, but here’s the parameters:

First level array designed by these parameters:

```
$construct  = 
array (size=3)
  0 => string '3' (length=1)
  1 => string '3' (length=1)
  2 => string '2' (length=1)
```

Second level parameters:

```
$ids =
array (size=8)
  0 => string '6100' (length=4)
  1 => string '6102' (length=4)
  2 => string '6101' (length=4)
  3 => string '1' (length=1)
  4 => string '7' (length=1)
  5 => string '5' (length=1)
  6 => string '2' (length=1)
  7 => string '6' (length=1)
```

The order of the second level $ids makes no difference.

Comment: shouldn't the result be `[6100,6102,6101][1,7,5][2,6]`..... are you trying to do an [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) the hard way?

Comment: Leaving aside the facts that a) you are not asking a specific question and b) you are not showing any effort, just asking for code -- **how on earth are we supposed to know the rules for splitting the ids into chunks**? You have ruled out the only *obvious* way "grab them starting from the top".

Comment: I'm actually trying to fix the array_chunk.  The array_chunk doesn't take into account remainders in this particular scenario.  The array sizes are extremely variable.  The final array needs to follow the pattern explicitly defined by the $construct variable.

Comment: @Patrick So, basically, you want two arrays of size 3 and one of size 2, any element goes anywhere?

Comment: Correct, but the construction must follow the $construct rule.  In another scenario, it could be 5 arrays with 3 arrays each containing two, and 2 arrays each containing just one.  Follow?  I've been playing with array_slice and array_fill.  struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I think you're asking. You may (if required) want to add your own error checking if `$construct` demands more elements than exist in `$ids`.

```php
$ids = array('6100', '6102', '6101', '1', '7', '5', '2', '6');
$construct = array('3', '3', '2');

$result = array();

for($i=0, $c=0; $c < count($construct); $i+=$construct[$c], $c+=1)
  array_push($result, array_slice($ids, $i, $construct[$c]));

var_dump($result);

>>> array(3) { 
               [0]=> array(3) { [0]=>"6100", [1]=>"6102", [2]=>"6101" }
               [1]=> array(3) { [0]=>"1",    [1]=>"7",    [2]=>"5"    }
               [2]=> array(2) { [0]=>"2",    [1]=>"6"                 }
             }
```

Comment: That's got it exactly.  Thank you.  I know it wasn't much to go on... and I appreciate your patience and help (unlike some other annoyed users).